# Django custom page based CMS

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I am searching for django CMS that allows me to create something like custom pages build from predefined components.

Every page should be builded from custom "inpage" components like:

- carousel with images
- gallery with images
- richtext field
- plain text field

So as a developer I will build a template for every page of a website from this components and assing a CSS file for the given page. For example one page can look like:

- plain text field (heading)
- plain text field (some kind of page abstract)
- richtext field (part of the text)
- gallery with images (few specified images with some style)
- richtext field (another part of the text)

Another page could be build in a different way. The key idea is, that **every page will have predefined unique layout** (template) that is not breakable by users in CMS.

The CMS I would like to use, should allow the user to change content of the particular componets for particular page. So the **CMS should create form to change the content of the particular components for a given page** (heading, text, images in carousel).

**The changable content of the page (form fields) can be stored in database of files, it does not really matter**.

The main idea behind this concept is to prevent user from changing the layout provided by designer and enforce the correct styles and correct "content type" for every part of every page.

Note: I used a Mezzanine for last few years and it seems to me easier to code the proposed CMS from scratch rather than use the Mezzanine somehow in this way.

My questions:

- does something like exist?
- has this type of CMS a common name?

Sorry for being too broad, but I do not really how I can search such a thing (in case it already exists - or at least something similar). Any hint, comment or advice will be more than welcome.

Comment: There is a CMS system built on top of Django: wagtail.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Wagtail seems to be able to do exactly what I want so far. Please make a proper answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

your question is too broad but to answer it quickly:

1. I don't know that anything like this exactly already exists
2. There's no common name for this as far as I know.

You're asking two things - one, you want to create a website and give each user some control over the content they create (I suppose you're creating some blogging system or something). second, you want to use a CMS.

The problem with that, I think, is these two things are inherently unrelated. It feels like it's similar - you manage your content with the CMS, just like your users manage their content, but it's actually completely different. One is a tool for developers to quickly build a website, the other is a limited set of tools within an existing website that's exposed to the user. You will never want to expose any part of the CMS to your users, you'll want to have control over that, so it really doesn't matter if you use a CMS or not.

in short - sure, you can use any CMS to build your website, and you can build it from scratch. I'd prefer the latter cause I like building stuff from scratch, but it's really irrelevant to what you're trying to build.